# Python Shapes on grid

Tags: python

Have to make a program that given the option to input square or circle, user inputs width and a center x,y coordinate. 
What I don't understand is how to write code for if there are two shapes on a plane and how to identify if one is inside the other

I'm super helpless, and have no background in computer science. Thank you!

Comment: You need to break up your question. Do you want a library for drawing in python, do you want a solution to shape collation?

Comment: I guess it would be more of the shape collation.

Comment: By "one is inside the other" do you mean _completely_ inside or would you include the case where one is just overlapping the other?

Answer (score 0):

You have to address Circle in Circle, Circle in Square, Square in Circle, and Square in Square.  I suggest drawing some pictures with the centers marked, and observe their relationships.

**Circle in Circle**: the distance between the centers has to be less than the difference in radius's.

**Circle in Square**: Same as circle in circle *I think*

**Square in Circle**: The radius of the circle must be larger than the distance from the center of the square to a corner PLUS the distance between centers

**Square in Square**: you got this! solve yourself ;)